# Unable to save mongoose document : Schema type issue

Tags: mongoose

Im trying to save the mongoose data using postman the data seems to be saved.

But when im try to post using the API , no data gets saved.

In **postman** im posting something like:

> Headers  Content-Type: application/json

```
{
    "category_name": "Chats",
    "product_createdat": "12/7/17",
    "product_desc": "juice",
    "product_image": "mango_image",
    "product_name": "Banana juice",
    "product_price": "35",
    "product_status": "Active",
    "product_updatedat": "12/7/17"
}
```

**\var\www\html\Express\nodeauthapp-master\app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config/database');

// Connect To Database
mongoose.connect(config.database);

// On Connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('Connected to database '+config.database);
});

const app = express();
const products = require('./routes/products');

// Port Number
const port = 3000;

// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/products', products);

// Index Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send('Invalid Endpoint');
});

// Start Server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port '+port);
});
```

**\var\www\html\Express\nodeauthapp-master\routes\products.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('../config/database');
const Products = require('../models/products');

// Add Categories
router.post('/add', (req, res, next) => {

//res.send('Products addition');
//Create a model folder

   let newProduct = new Products({
        category_name: req.body.category_name,  
        product_name: req.body.product_name,
        product_price: req.body.product_price,
        product_image: req.body.product_image,
        product_desc: req.body.product_desc,
        product_status: req.body.product_status,
        product_createdat: req.body.product_createdat,
        product_updatedat: req.body.product_updatedat
    }); 


   Products.addProduct(newProduct, (err, products) => {
    if(err){
      res.json({success: false, msg:'Product unable to add'});
    } else {
      res.json({success: true, msg:'Products successfuly added!!'});
    }
     });
   });

module.exports = router;
```

**UPDATED:**

**\var\www\html\Express\nodeauthapp-master\models\products.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const config = require('../config/database');

// Products Schema
const ProductsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    category_name: {
    type: String
  },
  product_name: {
    type: String,
    //required: true  //had to change this to default
    default: true
  },
  product_price: {
    type: String,
    default: true
  },
  product_image: {
    type: String,
    default: true
  },
   product_desc: {
    type: String,
    default: true
 },
   product_status: {
    type: String,
    default: true
 },
   product_createdat: {
    type: String,
    required: true
 },
   product_updatedat: {
    type: String,
   default: true
 }
});

 const Products = module.exports = mongoose.model('Products', ProductsSchema);


module.exports.addProduct = function(newProduct, callback){
    //newProduct.save(callback);
    newProduct.save(function(err) { 
      // we've updated the dog into the db here if (err) throw err;
    });
}
```

In browser i get:

**success: false, msg:'Product unable to add'**

**UPDATED:**   I have full Frontend code of angular here:

[MongoDB : Data not saving via Angular 2 services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45073357/mongodb-data-not-saving-via-angular-2-services?noredirect=1#comment77119449_45073357)

In postman , i am passing the API endpoint

http://10.22.*.*:3000/products/add

[image]

Comment: `addProduct` is working without postman ???

Comment: Try this -   `newProduct.save(function(err) { 
                   // we've updated the dog into the db here
                   if (err) throw err;
                });`

Comment: have updated the question @Utkarsh Dubey, i see only object with data in the broswer, but data  isnt saving to DB and in postman i am saving via API

Comment: please check body-parser in your app.js settings.

Comment: i have app.use(bodyParser.json()); in my app.js, have updated my full app.js file

Comment: Ok problem was with required option in model file...i had to change to default: true, but with default, only the value 'true' gets added cause its default, how to store the actual value?

Comment: Is your problem resolve with @AtulAgrawal suggestion ??

Comment: I have included body parser in app.js and only 'true' values are inserting against each key if i give default: true in my schema type, but actual values are not inserting @UtkarshDubey

Comment: Why you give `default: true` in  `type: String`??

Comment: Try this -     `var schema = new Schema({
                        name: String,
                        role: { type: String, default: 'guitarist' }
                    });`

Comment: or Try this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector

Comment: could you please modify these lines  Products.addProduct(newProduct,  ```(err, products) => {if(err){res.json({success: false, msg:'Product unable to add'});} else {res.json({success: true, msg:'Products successfuly added!!'});}});});```
to```Products.addProduct(newProduct, (err, products) => {if(err){console.log('Error Here:',err); res.json({success: false, msg:'Product unable to add'});} else {res.json({success: true, msg:'Products successfuly added!!'}); }});});```   and paste error message here for better understanding

Comment: I tried with this :  category_name: req.body[0].category_name, and its saving